# How to implement SQLDependency caching in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

HI Can any one explain me how to implement SQL Dependency Caching in Asp.Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See David Hayden's [article](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/04/29/2929.aspx) on the subject for an example.

Generally you connect the dependency to a command and add the dependency when inserting into the cache.

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT something FROM dbo.ATable", connection);
var dependency = new SqlCacheDependency(command);
var result = ObtainResultUsingThe(command);

Cache.Insert("CacheKey", result, dependency);
```

Observe that special rules apply for your queries. Among others:

- Named columns must be selected (no SELECT *)
- Must use fully qualified name of table (e.g. dbo.ATable)

**Edit:**

For using the dependency in caching an entire page, you can follow [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

How you implement SQL dependency caching will depend on the version of SQL server you are using. I would suggest reading [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx) to get a better understanding of how it hangs together.

Answer (score 0):

hi answer with implementation can be found at below site

http://harismile.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/mvc-with-ef-sqldependencycache/